# CUDA Block Mean

Tags: multidimensional-array, cuda, race-condition

I am trying to find out block mean of 8*8 array onto the 4*4 array. Something like this: [image]

I am currently stuck on a race condition type conundrum where the values read by each thread varies everytime I run the program. Right now my only concern is to add all the block elements together, I will later on divide that sum I get. This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

const int MAIN_SIZE = 8;
const int RESULT_SIZE = 4;

typedef int mainArray[MAIN_SIZE];
typedef int resultArray[RESULT_SIZE];

__global__ void computeMean(mainArray *main, resultArray *result) {
    int mColumn = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int mRow = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (mRow >= MAIN_SIZE || mColumn >= MAIN_SIZE)
        return;

    // real calculation
    int rRow = std::floor(static_cast<float>(mRow / 2)),
        rColumn = std::floor(static_cast<float>(mColumn / 2));
    int x = result[rRow][rColumn] + main[mRow][mColumn];
    result[rRow][rColumn] += x;
    printf("Adding %d on %d %d at location %d %d; new value: %d\n", main[mRow][mColumn], mRow, mColumn, rRow, rColumn, result[rRow][rColumn]);
}

int main() {
    mainArray *hMain, *dMain;
    resultArray *hResult, *dResult;
    size_t mSize = MAIN_SIZE * MAIN_SIZE * sizeof(int*);
    size_t rSize = RESULT_SIZE * RESULT_SIZE * sizeof(int*);
    hMain = (mainArray *) malloc (mSize);
    hResult = (resultArray *) malloc (rSize);

    // populate arrays
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAIN_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < MAIN_SIZE; j++) {
            hMain[i][j] = ++k;
        }
    }
    memset(hResult, 0, rSize);

    printf("main\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < MAIN_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < MAIN_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", hMain[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("result\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < RESULT_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < RESULT_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", hResult[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Allocate memory on device
    cudaMalloc(&dMain, mSize);
    cudaMalloc(&dResult, rSize);

    // Do memcopies to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(dMain, hMain, mSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dResult, hResult, rSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 block(1, 1);
    dim3 grid ((MAIN_SIZE + block.x - 1) / block.x, (MAIN_SIZE + block.y - 1) / block.y);
    computeMean<<<grid, block>>>(dMain, dResult);

    // Do memcopies back to host
    cudaMemcpy(hMain, dMain, mSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(hResult, dResult, rSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // validate
    if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess) {printf("cuda error\n"); return -1;}

    printf("success!\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < RESULT_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < RESULT_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", hResult[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(hMain);
    free(hResult);
    cudaFree(dMain);
    cudaFree(dResult);
    return 0;
}
```

I am currently new on CUDA so if I am using the wrong approach from the start please do tell(I think my array is all wrong but I am just unable to allot dynamic space for the two dimensional one). Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have multiple threads reading and writing to the same location(s) in `result`.  So you have multiple kinds of hazards going on here.  The CUDA thread parallel architecture does not automatically resolve these for you.  You either need to arrange for unconflicted access (e.g. using a [classical parallel reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) technique) or else use something like [atomics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) to sort out the accesses.

Comment: Also, this: `mRow / 2` is integer division.  Period.  doing your static cast on the result and the `floor` operation is a bunch of meaningless wasted effort.  If you want a proper floating point floor, you'll need to cast one of the arguments to `float` **before** doing the division.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: You've answered OP's question, you should probably make that an answer.

Comment: @hraw: A couple more points in addition to those Robert has made: (1) You're adding x's but not dividing by 4 eventually. (2) If you're worried the division by 2 is somehow slow - don't be, it's just a left-shift of the bits of the number; not like a general integer division. (3) As a general reminder - using `printf()` changes the behavior of the launched grid, and the order of printf() results is not the order in which things happen in hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with this section of code:

```
int rRow = std::floor(static_cast<float>(mRow / 2)),
    rColumn = std::floor(static_cast<float>(mColumn / 2));
int x = result[rRow][rColumn] + main[mRow][mColumn];
result[rRow][rColumn] += x;
```

Because `rRow` and `rColumn` are found using integer division from `mRow` and `mColumn`, it should be evident that threads whose `threadIdx.x` is either 0 or 1 will produce the same `rColumn` result, and there are many other instances of duplication.  As a result, you have threads that are:

1. writing to the same location without any order or control
2. reading from a location that other threads may be writing to

CUDA doesn't sort these hazards out for you.  You must take specific programming steps to deal with them.  (You also have a logical error in that you are adding the main data to the existing result data, then adding that sum **again** to your result data; I'm reasonably sure this is not what you want.)  The two typical approaches to resolve the thread hazards would be either:

1. Use [atomics](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions)
2. Use a [classical parallel reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) method

For simplicity, I'll present a reworked code that demonstrates the first method.

```
$ cat t1324.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

const int MAIN_SIZE = 8;
const int RESULT_SIZE = 4;

typedef int mainArray[MAIN_SIZE];
typedef int resultArray[RESULT_SIZE];

__global__ void computeMean(mainArray *main, resultArray *result) {
    int mColumn = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int mRow = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    if (mRow >= MAIN_SIZE || mColumn >= MAIN_SIZE)
        return;

    // real calculation
    int rRow = std::floor(static_cast<float>(mRow / 2)),
        rColumn = std::floor(static_cast<float>(mColumn / 2));
    //int x = result[rRow][rColumn] + main[mRow][mColumn];
    //result[rRow][rColumn] += x;
    atomicAdd(&(result[rRow][rColumn]), main[mRow][mColumn]);
    //printf("Adding %d on %d %d at location %d %d; new value: %d\n", main[mRow][mColumn], mRow, mColumn, rRow, rColumn, result[rRow][rColumn]);
}

int main() {
    mainArray *hMain, *dMain;
    resultArray *hResult, *dResult;
    size_t mSize = MAIN_SIZE * MAIN_SIZE * sizeof(int*);
    size_t rSize = RESULT_SIZE * RESULT_SIZE * sizeof(int*);
    hMain = (mainArray *) malloc (mSize);
    hResult = (resultArray *) malloc (rSize);

    // populate arrays
    //int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAIN_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < MAIN_SIZE; j++) {
            hMain[i][j] = 1; //++k;
        }
    }
    memset(hResult, 0, rSize);

    printf("main\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < MAIN_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < MAIN_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", hMain[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("result\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < RESULT_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < RESULT_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", hResult[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Allocate memory on device
    cudaMalloc(&dMain, mSize);
    cudaMalloc(&dResult, rSize);

    // Do memcopies to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(dMain, hMain, mSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dResult, hResult, rSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 block(1, 1);
    dim3 grid ((MAIN_SIZE + block.x - 1) / block.x, (MAIN_SIZE + block.y - 1) / block.y);
    computeMean<<<grid, block>>>(dMain, dResult);

    // Do memcopies back to host
    cudaMemcpy(hMain, dMain, mSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(hResult, dResult, rSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // validate
    if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess) {printf("cuda error\n"); return -1;}

    printf("success!\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < RESULT_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < RESULT_SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", hResult[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(hMain);
    free(hResult);
    cudaFree(dMain);
    cudaFree(dResult);
    return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -o t1324 t1324.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1324
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
main
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
result
0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0
success!
4  4  4  4
4  4  4  4
4  4  4  4
4  4  4  4
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

A few other notes:

1. I changed the initialization data so I could quickly identify correct output.
2. Your code here:

   ```
   int rRow = std::floor(static_cast<float>(mRow / 2)),
   ```

   I believe is not doing what you think.  `mRow/2` is integer division as you have written it.  The subsequent cast to `float` and then taking the `floor` has no effect, I don't think.  It's not hurting anything that I can see (I'm pretty sure you want integer division here), so I've left it as-is.  If you want floating-point division, you need to start by casting one of your two integer operands to floating point.  The code you have written does not do that. (It casts the result.)

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I did end up solving it my self using atomic add after all. But thanks for taking the time this is exactly what I also did. FYI the reason I wrote that `int rRow = std::floor(static_cast<float>(mRow / 2))` was because for in division if the answer produced is 2.5 then it automatically converts to 3 which I don't want hence I converted it to float and then took the floor value.